# How to get enable freeshipping for special customers in magento, according to a custom attribute

Tags: magento, checkout

At checkout page, customer will have option for freeshipping, regardless of minimum amount set in admin panel for freeshipping.

I have succesfully made enable/disable freeshipping, but in case of less than minimum amount freeshipping is not available.

my code is below, I have extended Mage_Shipping_Model_Shipping.

```
protected function _checkCarrierAvailability($carrierCode, $request = null)
{

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();

    if($carrierCode == 'freeshipping' && !$customer->getData('enable_free_shipping')){
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: it's not clear what do you want to have? Because it's actually default magento behaviour and magento filters it out automatically.

Comment: Do you want apply free shipping to special customers or do you want set free shipping criteria based on order amount ? Kindly clerify.

Comment: IF in case its both combine, they you will have to fetch minimum order value from config and put that with "&&" within your condition.

Comment: lets say i have set minimum order amount for freeshipping as 75, and I want some customers to have freeshipping even they have order amount less than 75.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it by hooking Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping.

in etc.xml

```
        <salesrule>
            <rewrite>
                <quote_freeshipping>Company_Module_Model_Freeshipping</quote_freeshipping>
            </rewrite>
        </salesrule>
```

and in Model/Freeshipping.php

```
class Company_Module_Model_Freeshipping extends Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping{
/**
 * Collect information about free shipping for all address items
 *
 * @param   Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address
 * @return  Mage_SalesRule_Model_Quote_Freeshipping
 */
public function collect(Mage_Sales_Model_Quote_Address $address)
{
    parent::collect($address);
    $quote = $address->getQuote();
    $store = Mage::app()->getStore($quote->getStoreId());

    $address->setFreeShipping(0);
    $items = $this->_getAddressItems($address);
    if (!count($items)) {
        return $this;
    }
    $this->_calculator->init($store->getWebsiteId(), $quote->getCustomerGroupId(), $quote->getCouponCode());

    $isAllFree = true;
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        if ($item->getNoDiscount()) {
            $isAllFree = false;
            $item->setFreeShipping(false);
        } else {
            /**
             * Child item discount we calculate for parent
             */
            if ($item->getParentItemId()) {
                continue;
            }
            $this->_calculator->processFreeShipping($item);
            $isItemFree = (bool)$item->getFreeShipping();
            $isAllFree = $isAllFree && $isItemFree;
            if ($item->getHasChildren() && $item->isChildrenCalculated()) {
                foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                    $this->_calculator->processFreeShipping($child);
                    /**
                     * Parent free shipping we apply to all children
                    */
                    if ($isItemFree) {
                        $child->setFreeShipping($isItemFree);
                    }

                }
            }
        }
    }
    if ($isAllFree && !$address->getFreeShipping()) {
        $address->setFreeShipping(true);
    }

    // Magic works here

    $customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
    if($customer->getData('enable_free_shipping'))
    {
        $address->setFreeShipping(true);
    }
    return $this;

}}
```

Hope this helps somebody needed.

Answer (score 1):

Anurag, Super simple!!!

An example: I will be offering free shipping on all orders over $50 to specific customers

Create a new customer group "Free Shipping over $50 Customers"

Create a new shopping cart price rule.  In general,  select only this new customer group because I didn't have any new customer groups in my screen shots i just used retailer to provide an example, but you would select your new customer group

Set the rule to automatically apply with no coupon code

All details provided in screen shots.

Lastly,  go into customers->manage customers,  find the one you want to change,  and go into this specific customer and change their group to the newly created one

Again, this rule can be changed to whatever you want it to be.   This is the same way you offer discounts to specific high spending customers or VIP customers etc.   Any questions please feel free to ask

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: Thanks Rob for your answer, but creating new customer group won't be any help to me. cause website has more than 200 customer groups and re-indexing is continuous problem for me. Let me share what I have done.